# How unique is the drive id in Office365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When performing the Graph request `/me/drive` you are able to retrieve the `id` of the drive.

I'm wondering how unique this `id` is. Is it only unique in your tenant or is it unique in the whole Office 365 / Microsoft cloud?

Answer (score -1):

It should be unique in the whole O365/Microsoft cloud, so Microsoft can maintenance the rule in the later period,just like the GUID. Of course, the id format rule are different from OneDrive(e.g. 3c67c2629e95add3) and OneDrive-For-Business(e.g. 05kpQIVuAkebEbnq3ftalG9eKBXqLXRJiiiQGZjVlDqML5T888BfS4YjkXMj9Exl).

You can see the definition of the Graph:
Microsoft Graph is the gateway to data and intelligence in Microsoft 365. Microsoft Graph provides a unified programmability model that you can use to take advantage of the tremendous amount of data in Office 365, Enterprise Mobility + Security, and Windows 10.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview

The onedrive id maybe fully public, so it should be unique identity.
The onedrive-for-business maybe private, so it maybe not unique. But for the standardization, it should be unique identity too.